# Azure Webjob publish takes entire bin folder contents

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, project-settings

I was trying "**Publish as azure webjob**" option on a webjob project. It copies entire bin contents to cloud. It includes other unwanted dlls or files also (example: unit test dlls or any other file in the bin folder). How can we include only those contents which are required by my webjob?

**For a webAPI project I can find a option as follows: (but not for WebJob)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the project release/ publish settings. You can exclude test project from 'Configuration Manager'. 
Unit test project should only be enabled in Debug mode. You can also use [Ignore] switch. It's a build switch and will ignore the tests from being published.

Comment: It is not just about the test projects binaries, any file inside the bin folder at the time of publish will get uploaded; those files which are not part of the webjob should not be published. This what I am looking at.

Comment: What are other types of files? If those are pdb files, you may have to 'clean' the solution and change to 'Release' mode and publish.